# C# Telegram.Bot - download image sent by user

Tags: c#, .net, telegram-bot

I am writing a Telegram bot with the latest version of Telegram.Bot library for C#. I am trying to make bot download an image sent by user.

```
if (message.Photo == null) {
    noPictureErrorMenu(botClient, message);
}
else {
    await downloadPicture(
        botClient,
        message.Photo[message.Photo.Length - 1].FileId, 
        @$"pictures\{userList[currentUserIndex].currentObjectiveId}.jpg"
    );

    Console.WriteLine("Image successfully downloaded!");
    
    userList[currentUserIndex].userEditingPitcure = false;
    userList[currentUserIndex].userEditingDeadline = true;
    deadlineEditMenu(botClient, message);
}
```

However it only responds to the message when message.Photo equals null. When I send a photo it acts like no message has been sent at all (doesn't even access the downloadPicture function). Here is the downloadPicture function:

```
// Download a picture send by user
public static async Task downloadPicture(ITelegramBotClient botClient, string fileId, string path){
    Console.WriteLine("Function 'downloadPicture' accessed.");
    try {
        var file = await botClient.GetFileAsync(fileId);
        using (FileStream imageSaver = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create)) {
            await botClient.DownloadFileAsync(file.FilePath, imageSaver);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        Console.WriteLine("Error downloading image!");
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: no errors thrown? do you see the info logs?

Comment: no, absolutely nothing, even the first line of the downloadPicture function doesn't execute.